# How can i convert this javascript function to jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Im using this javacript function to print div, but i realized that i need it to be in jquery. Can someone help me to do this in jquery?

```
    function printData()
    {

        var divToPrint=document.getElementById("printWayBill");
        newWin= window.open("");
        newWin.document.write('<html><head><style> @media print { .page-break { page-break-after: always; } } </style></head><body>');
        newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
        newWin.document.write('</body></html>');
        newWin.document.getElementById('printWayBill').style.display='block'
        newWin.print();
        newWin.close();

    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? What's not working?

Comment: *«i realized that i need it to be in jquery»* - Why? The waybill needs jQuery to display correctly? --- Create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to change

```
getElementById('myId');
```

By the corresponding selector :

```
$('#myId')
```

And to use the html() function instead of document.write...